# Google Fonts within enterprise applications?

Tags: font, google, applications, enterprise

I know that using Google Fonts for websites are no cost but what about embedding those fonts within an enterprise application that the user doesn't access through the web? I've yet to see anything from Google talking about this but assumed someone has dealt with the issue. I know a contractor that worked with the Google Fonts team that said it was ok but that's far from making things sound water tight and protecting against a law suit down the line, should we embed their fonts within our application. :) Any knowledge on this or from anyone that has done it, how you did the credits in the app, etc., would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think questions about licensing are on-topic on UX (there is a specific SE site for that and/or _contact_ form on Google pages).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not UX related.

Comment: The potential income from font licensing would be almost laughable on Google's books. This one is for the good of the people.

Comment: I wonder how this question could be improved to make it on-topic for Graphic Design in preparation for a migration there.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to pull it back into building applications, etc. No problem having it closed or moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technically isn't the right place to ask the question... but all fonts offered by Google are open source fonts. You can freely use it, embed it or modify it to your heart's content.

> All of the fonts are Open Source. This means that you are free to share your favorites with friends and colleagues. You can even customize them for your own use, or collaborate with the original designer to improve them. And **you can use them in every way you want, privately or commercially** — in print, on your computer, or in your websites.

https://www.google.com/fonts#AboutPlace:about (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks so much, Nightning. That was what we were looking for. Earlier last year we had seen some different Terms of Use for it but nothing seemed written out so concrete. This works! Thanks again! My concerns were that if it was being distributed in our applications that people were downloading, if that changed the terms.